# How to pass param from controller to service in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openweathermap

I'm currently working on a project to help me better understand angularjs! I am currently stuck on how to pass a parameter from the controller to service.

In my program, I have created a function called "GetForecastByLocation" when a user types in an input clicks on a button. From there I want to take their input and then pass it to the http call in service.js.

Originally, $http.get was in a long giant string of the API url, but I googled around and it seems that I'm supposed to use parameters when trying to change a portion of the string. As of right now, I know parameter is hardcoded to a specific city, but I want to take new input and pass the value of vm.city to the $http.get call.

If any one can help I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

controller.js

```
    var app = angular.module('weatherApp.controllers', [])
    app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope','Data',
        function($scope, Data) {

        $scope.getForecastByLocation = function(myName) {
            $scope.city = myName;
            Data.getApps($scope.city);},

        Data.getApps(city)
        .then(function(data)){
        //doing a bunch of things like converting units, etc
        },
        function(res){
            if(res.status === 500) {
            // server error, alert user somehow
        } else { 
            // probably deal with these errors differently
        }
        }); // end of function
}]) // end of controller
```

service.js

```
.factory('Data', function($http, $q) {
       var data = [],
           lastRequestFailed = true,
           promise;
       return {
          getApps: function() {
             if(!promise || lastRequestFailed) {
            promise = $http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?',{
              params: {
                q: Tokyo,
              }
            })
            .then(function(res) {
                lastRequestFailed = false;
                data = res.data;
                return data;
            }, function(res) {
                return $q.reject(res);
            });
         }
         return promise;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Why not add a parameter to `getApps`?  The factory would look like `getApps: function(city){ ...` and the callsite like `Data.getApps($scope.city)`

Comment: hi @wilusdaman! Sorry but I'm very new to angularjs. If you can show the full code/elaborate i would greatly appreciate it! Thank you! //In your code, would I still need params? If I'm understanding correctly, the value from function(city) fill in q: city, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arguments to a factory method is no different than passing arguments to a plain old function.

First, set up `getApps` to accept a parameter:

```
.factory('Data', function($http, $q){
    // ...
    return {
        getApps: function(city){
            promise = $http.get(URL, {
                params: {q: city}
            }).then( /* ... */ );
            // ...
            return promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Then pass it your argument:

```
$scope.getForecastByLocation = function(myName) {
    $scope.city = myName;
    Data.getApps($scope.city);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I know this will work because I tried passing in a parameter and it changed. I hope this is okay to ask, but I have follow up question. So earlier, I didn't show my entire controller.js code and now I have updated it, but the function called after the button is clicked is not sending the city to the service. I'm thinking this because of maybe where I placed getForecastbyLocation in the controller. I think it's in the wrong place, but I'm not sure where to place it. Do you have any suggestions/advice? Once again thank you!

Comment: what does your `ng-click` look like?

Comment: It currently looks like this `<md-button class="md-raised"  ng-click="getForecastByLocation(myName)">SUBMIT</md-button>`

Comment: Gotcha. I think you need `getForecastByLocation(city)` since `$scope.city` exists and `$scope.myName` doesn't (or that's how it seems from the code you've shared)

Comment: Would the placement of `$scope.getForecastByLocation` matter in the controller? Or is the original placement shown in the code okay?

Comment: It's just an assignment, so no, the order shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like setting a value to a function's context variable.

**Services.js**

Simple example of a service.

```
.factory('RouteService', function() {
    var route = {}; // $Object

    var setRoute_ = function(obj)
    {
        return route = obj;
    };

    var getRoute_ = function()
    {
        if(typeof route == 'string')
        {
            return JSON.parse(route);
        }

        return null;
    };

    return {
        setRoute: setRoute_,
        getRoute: getRoute_
    };
})
```

**Controllers.js**

Simple example of Service usage:

```
.controller('RoutesCtrl', function ($scope, RouteService) {
    // This is only the set part.
    var route = {
        'some_key': 'some_value'
    };

    RouteService.setRoute(route);
})
```